# How to append to an array horizontally in 2 rows

Tags: python, arrays

I have code here that only appends going down the array and creates a single column. I would like for the two values to be appended side by side and create 2 rows going horizontally. How can I do this? Here is the code:

```
rs = np.array([237804, -1.84038e+06])
pos = np.array([[],[]])
pos = np.append(pos,[rs[0],rs[1]])
```

The result is:

[image]

The desired result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. I specified `axis=0`. It does not work when you initialize `pos = np.array([[],[]])`. It needs to have values or it will return error. Here is what I did.

```
rs = np.array([4, 5])
pos = np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])
pos = np.append(pos, [[rs[0],rs[1]]], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]]
```